# After update, i cant see albert launcher, and i need to get to settings non-gui way

Tags: settings

Albert launcher, after update, can't show at all. It was because i chose other display settings, and now I can't go to settings. Anyone know alternative way to launch albert settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove albert's config file.

```
rm .config/albert/albert.conf
```

Comment: This solution also works if some commands start to miss behaving after the update. In my case shutdown won't work. after removing config file it works now. Thanks.